# Robot Framework For Loop with RIDE

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am having issues creating for loops while using RIDE 1.7.4 for robot framework 3.1.2
When i create a simple test I have several scenario's happening:

1. ```
   Test
       FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    10
           Log    ${i}
       END
   ```

This creates the error: Non-existing variable '${i}'.
To bypass this, I tried adding the variable, both inline and as a suite variable before. In both cases the result was the same

2.

```
Test
    ${i}    Set variable    1
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    10
        Log    ${i}
    END
```

This creates the error: 'For' is a reserved keyword

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I have RIDE version 1.7.4 (and also tried 1.7.4.1), running on Python 3.7.6 and Robot Framework 3.1.2

Below is my pip list

```
Package             Version
------------------- -----------
numpy               1.16.6
Pillow              6.2.2
pip                 20.0.2
Pygments            2.5.2
PyPubSub            3.3.0
pywin32             227
robotframework      3.1.2
robotframework-ride 1.7.4
selenium            3.8.1
setuptools          41.2.0
six                 1.13.0
urllib3             1.25.7
wxPython            4.0.7.post2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. The problem is not in RIDE nor robotframework, but in the client running my testcases, which is still using Python 2.7, and possibly an older version of RF, which I guess is not compatible.

Comment: Even so, it is not clear why it failed. The test cases look OK for robot 3.1.2.